# Using JQuery to dynamically check if no of radio button many group has been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-group

I know this question had a lots of related resources. But, Still i need a perfect solution.

I have generated five number of radio buttons group dynamically. Each group holds upto five radio buttons. I have validated *"none checked in"* and *"at least one checked in feature"* as an individual group.

My question is, **How do I validate whether "All the groups are checked"**

for ref:
[image]

My code Below:

```
var names = [];

$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    // Creates an array with the names of all the different checkbox group.
    names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
});

// Goes through all the names and make sure there's at least one checked.
for (name in names) {
    var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + name + "']");
    if (radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
        alert('none checked in ' + name);
    } 
    else{
        // At least one checked
        var val = radio_buttons.val();
    }
}
```

I need to redirect to other page when all the radio button groups are checked. Its a bit simple. But, look complex for me.

Please Help.

**UPDATE**
My generated HTML for first two groups.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="optionsContainer"><div id="ratingContainer">
    <ul class="0">
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Strongly disagree" name="0" id="1"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Disagree" name="0" id="2"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Neutral" name="0" id="3"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Agree" name="0" id="4"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Strongly agree" name="0" id="5"></div></li>
    </ul></div></div></div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="optionsContainer"><div id="ratingContainer">
    <ul class="0">
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Strongly disagree" name="1" id="1"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Disagree" name="1" id="2"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Neutral" name="1" id="3"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Agree" name="1" id="4"></div></li>
        <li onclick="checkThis(this);"><div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" value="Strongly agree" name="1" id="5"></div></li>
    </ul></div></div></div>
```

*note:* Here group name alone gets changed.

Comment: Can you provide your JS Fiddle ?

Comment: You code looks fine, but there's no need for the second loop. Just move the check into the first loop

Comment: _"My question is, How do I validate whether "All the groups are checked""_ Is requirement to check if at least one checkbox is checked in each group, or _all_ checkboxes is each group are checked ?

Comment: @guest271314 At least one box checked in each groups

Comment: Does each group have a different parent element ? Can include `html` ?

Comment: `id` values should be unique. `id="ratingContainer"` is used twice.

Comment: I hope, Giving same id twice will not stop the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/eu6L1f80/2/

**Javascript:**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var checkboxes = {};
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        checkboxes[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });

    $.each(checkboxes, function(i, val) {
        if($(':checkbox[name='+i+']').is(':checked')) delete checkboxes[i];
    });

    if (!Object.keys(checkboxes).length) {
        alert('success!');
    } else {
        alert('error!');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div>
        Group:
        <input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Group:
        <input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Group:
        <input type="checkbox" name="group3" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="group3" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="group3" value="" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

Comment: Code looks fine for this static go. For dynamic call at '.group' seems confusing. Honestly, i do not know what to enter at .group position from my code!! :(

Comment: I've updated my answer more suitable to your needs. It now loops through all checkbox groups with the same name and checks if one these groups has at least one checked checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Changed

`<div id="ratingContainer">`

to

`<div class="ratingContainer">` .

Removed

`onclick="checkThis(this);"`

from html , added one event handler for all input elements

`elems.find("input").on("change", checkThis);`

Try

```js
var allChecked = false;

var names = [];

var elems = $(".0");

function checkThis(e) {
  var name = e.target.name;
  if (names.length < elems.length) {
    names.push(name);
  };

  allChecked = elems.get().every(function(el, i) {
    return $(el).find(":checked").is("*")
  });

  alert(name + " checked");

  if (allChecked) {
    // do stuff
    alert(names.join(" and ") + " checked, " + "allChecked:" + allChecked);
  };

};

elems.find("input").on("change", checkThis);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="optionsContainer">
    <div class="ratingContainer">
      <ul class="0">
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Strongly disagree" name="0" id="1">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Disagree" name="0" id="2">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Neutral" name="0" id="3">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Agree" name="0" id="4">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Strongly agree" name="0" id="5">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="optionsContainer">
    <div class="ratingContainer">
      <ul class="0">
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Strongly disagree" name="1" id="1">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Disagree" name="1" id="2">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Neutral" name="1" id="3">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Agree" name="1" id="4">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-radio">
            <input type="radio" value="Strongly agree" name="1" id="5">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine for me. But, i need to get the name attribute dynamically (0 to 4) in '$(".0")' here.

Comment: @rajmathan _" i need to get the name attribute dynamically (0 to 4) in '$(".0")' here"_ At each `change` event ?

Comment: Nope,User need a button click. Event should trigger only after selecting all groups element.

Comment: Sorry. Undefined Error. Anyway, Thanks for your Time.

Comment: @rajmathan Due to `onclick="checkThis(this);"` being attached to `li` element , the `li` can be clicked and call `checkThis` even if `input` element not actually checked. Updating stacksnippets .

Comment: @rajmathan See updated post. Removed `onclick="checkThis(this);" ` from `html` , added one event handler for all input elements `elems.find("input").on("change", checkThis);`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already know how to count up the checked elements. If you put that in the first loop, you can mark a variable false if any come up empty.

```
var names = [];
var allChecked = true;

$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    // Creates an array with the names of all the different checkbox group.
    names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    if $(this).filter(':checked').length === 0 {
        allChecked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't occur. Let me try again. Thanks for your code.